# Bug? Duplicated comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161367/question-about-number/3161607#3161607),  Robert William Hanks has three of the same comment, and all three claim to be upvoted by me.  But at the time the comment was originally posted, there was only one comment there, and that was the only thing I upvoted.

Just thought you'd like to know.

Here is a screen-shot (9/3/10):

[image: screenshot]

It happens from multiple computers and multiple browsers, but only when I am logged in; I see only one comment when I'm logged-out.

Comment: I can only see one comment. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I only see one comment by @RWH, and it was made a couple of hours after two other comments.  Are you seeing the same time stamp on all three comments?

Comment: CTRL+F5 - CTRL+F5 - CTRL+F5 - controlplusffive - Does that change anything?

Comment: Were you shaking your monitor when you took the screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now; see [Weird duplicate comment bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103841/weird-duplicate-comment-bug/103865#103865).

In your case, I'm pretty sure there must have been some database connection issue at the moment you cast your vote. Hard to say in hindsight, but either way, you'll only see the comment once after the next build.

Comment: something similar? [Comment duplication problem has been duplicated, again! Bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314689/303080)