# Weird duplicate comment bug

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, comments

I am seeing the same issue with duplicated comments as in [Bug? Duplicated comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57779/bug-duplicated-comment) (unresolved), in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185857/how-to-what-added-in-sys-path-append but I have some more information which might help to recreate the bug.

There was a comment which I was going to flag as offensive, unfortunately I accidentally clicked upvote and then I didn't seem able to flag it again after that.  I went 'back' on the browser and flagged it.  Then there appeared a duplicate comment, both of which I appear to have upvoted, but only appearing when I'm signed in. When I log out it's gone, and when I log in again it's back.

[image: logged-in]

[image: logged-out]

By the way, it was slightly annoying to have cast a vote like 'this is a great comment' when I was actually intending to say this is an offensive comment.  Could it be possible to undo comment upvotes, like you can with Q and A posts, or at least not remove the vote to flag?

Comment: C[hanging wrong votes on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) is one of the most upvoted status-declined feature-requests that are out there.  Please throw another vote on the fire.

Comment: @Lance: I gave it an upvote. I have often wanted to quickly retract a comment vote immediately after clicking the arrow - but alas, not currently possible.

Comment: Totally reproduced; thanks for the steps. Looking at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were two issues at play here:

1. The server didn't enforce the "either flag or upvote, not both" rule. While the UI enforces this, there are obivously ways around it – like the one you found.
2. The code that fetches the comments relied on the fact that the user has only voted (i.e. upvoted or flagged) once. While that's a reasonable assumption, there are edge cases where this may not be true (two I can think off: the one you found, and a connection hickup between the DB server and the web server – the latter is likely what happened in [the other case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57779/bug-duplicated-comment)).

Part 1 is fixed by enforcing the rule on the server as well.

Part 2 is fixed by considering this edge case and picking up each comment only once, even if a duplicate vote/flag somehow made it through. As I said, that's very unlikely, but since we cannot enforce this, say, through a UNIQUEness constraint in the database (due to the way the data is stored), it's not impossible. For perspective: Out of close to 9 million comments on Stack Overflow, yours was the *fourth* where this happened.

(Fix will go out with the next build.)

Comment: impressive turnaround !