# Comment duplication problem has been duplicated, again! Bug?

Tags: bug, comments, edits, comment-edits

This just happened. I was editing a comment to add some additional text. When I was finished, two comments resulted, with the edited comment appearing *above* the unedited version.

The timestamp tooltip on the upper, longer, edited version is `04:43:15Z` whereas the timestamp on the lower, shorter, unedited one is *later* at `04:43:38`!

I'm not sure if this rises to the level of a meta question, but I don't know of a separate potential bug-reporting method.

Comments in question (the last two in the screenshot) are on [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30287/12102). Click for larger view.

> [image: screenshot of space.stackexchange /a/30287/12102]

**Update, Feb 28, 2019:** It just happened again [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34500/12102), internet was indeed "[flaky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314689/comment-was-duplicated-when-editing-bug#comment1031452_314689)" at the time:

> [image]

**Update, Mar 4, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34496/12102), and yes, connection was "flaky" again. The term comes from comments, my connection here is very slow at the moment.

> [image]

**Update, Mar 7, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/464867/83380)

> [image]

**Update, Mar 9, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34710/12102) when comment first posted (no editing)

> [image]

**Update, Mar 11, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34583/12102)

> [image]

**Update, Mar 16, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34847/12102)

> [image]

**Update, Mar 18, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111161/16035)

> [image]

**Update, Mar 27, 2019:** It just happened again, again [here **in chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49668411#49668411) I was given the option to *Retry* and clicked it.

> [image]

**I'm not going to continue to post events that are similar, and I'll instead make a note *if it stops happening*.

Comment: You can report bugs on any Meta site, so this question is fine.

Comment: Could it be that your network connection was flaky at the time? That is the only situation I've seen before that causes these kind of weird things.

Comment: All edits on above comments worked for me without any issues. So no repro for now in Chrome/Win10

Comment: @rene I don't have "flaky detection" software installed right now, but at the time I was using a shared WiFi router sitting on a water heater in a hallway that occasionally stops cooperating. My MacOS WiFi debugging feature then reports several problems when that happens. While that didn't happen today, the connection is in general therefore less than ideal. I've also had [this](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/960/12102) and also [this](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/983/12102) have happen in the past, from the same location.

Comment: Get a better server/connection/card? If this is a problem at your end, someone mentioned a "flaky" connection, I don't see what SE can do for you and I don't see how updating your problem is helpful. Maybe try the solutions offered here https://lifehacker.com/how-to-troubleshoot-a-flaky-internet-connection-5319976

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's not "what SE can do for you", it's what I can do for SE. What I can do is report unusual behavior and make a small collection of instances in case it is helpful for analysis. I have no idea of the cause, if on this end could be neighborhood or ISP. If SE decides they are not interested in this information, someone will tell me.

Comment: But if the problem is at your end, and you haven't denied this possibility, why not perform checks and confirm it or see if you can fix it. See if it's a problem of software, platform or if it's a question of poor internet connection. There must be ways of finding this out other than seeing comments being duplicated.

Comment: You've also said `and yes, connection was "flaky" again.` I mean, I lose Internet connection every day, every *single* day, which  that means I can't upload comments, I lose posts, I can't refresh etc . That doesn't mean I post on Meta reporting every instance my Internet (or my mac, I still haven't figured out who's to blame) falters or stops. P.S I actually posted a link. P.P.S "at your end" does not mean it's your fault.

Comment: @Mari-LouA rather than a series of comments, maybe you or someone else can add an answer explaining how I can check if these double-comments are caused at my end. If it's something reasonable that can provide useful information, I'll give it a try. But I think *generating a dialogue suggesting without evidence that it's my fault could be distracting.* Let's keep the focus on the site's behavior.

Comment: You're definitely sending multiple requests to the system which is what is causing the duplicate comments. Nothing in our code auto-retries submitting something if the request failed. Perhaps your system is doing something to retry a request it thinks failed because it got no response in time? What OS and browser are you using? Are you not getting any sort of error message in between the first comment submission and the second one? If you ever get the chance to see the console / network requests info in the browser's dev tools after this situation, it'd probably be really helpful.

Comment: @animuson MacOS and Chrome. I'm not a developer but if you can describe what I should look at/for (or point me at something I can read) I can keep an eye out and make a screen shot like https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FVMz.png or grab text or save something. Thanks!

Comment: @animuson I've just had this happen again twice from a Starbucks WiFi https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dvUq.png links: [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following#comment58614_32034), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following#comment58616_32034) no error messages, it just looks the same as it does when there's a few second delay during normal "busy WiFi " activity. (fyi this is probably [unrelated](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1291/12102))

Comment: @animuson other Starbucks instance was [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32074/7982).